# Group by in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have following table. with amount and one paid field

```
partner               sale_order   Amount     Paid             
Administrator         s0002         100       done         
Administrator         s0007         100       
Administrator         s0004         100       done
Administrator         s0009         100
Administrator         s0003         100
Demo User             s0001         200       done
Demo User             s0005         200       done
Demo User             s0008         200
```

My Desire output will be

```
   partner          amount       paid_amount
Administrator        500           200
    s0002            100           100 
    s0007            100 
    s0004            100           100  
    s0009            100
    s0003            100
    s0006            100
Demo User            600           400  
    s0001            200           200 
    s0008            200           200  
    s0005            200
```

Is this possible?
This is edited one. This is edited second time, if possible or not?

Comment: looks like you're really new to SQL. Output in SQL usually is table with rows and columns. Does your desired output has one or two columns?

Comment: Yes here total_amount column is there but at this time I require this output in single row like desire output.

Comment: Not sure that this is what you need, but to get this output in one column you can do `select distinct partner from table1 union all select sale_order from table1`

Comment: This is nearest to output, But it display first two partner name and than display sale_order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with cte(partner, amount, sort, sort2) as (
    select
        partner, sum(amount), partner, 0
    from table1
    group by partner

    union all

    select
        sale_order, amount, partner, 1
    from table1
)
select data, amount
from cte
order by sort, sort2
```

Comment: Now suppose I add another column like amount than what will be change in query ?? And it possible to add total of amount is display with sub amount like desire output?

Comment: @ShyamSolanki changed the answer

Comment: It join in only one column not display amount column separately.

Comment: @ShyamSolanki yes it's possible

Answer (score 0):

Simpler solution:

```
SELECT sale_order FROM 
(
   select partner, sale_order from tablename
   UNION
   select partner||'1',partner FROM tablename
)
AS temp
ORDER BY partner desc
```

Comment: suppose you have partners 'P' and 'P1' in your table. Will this one be ordered correctly?

Comment: yes this is fine, but I add another column like amount than I want output in two column first columns is same as desire output and second column is amount column in first level like p1 ----> total_amount and under p1 all sale_order -- saleorder amount.

Comment: I think it's more performance wise to use distinct + union all instead of union

Comment: I just wrote a simple solution to the specific problem that doesn't require a "with query", use Roman Pekars answer for a general solution

Comment: @Ratzor actually my cte could be easily rewritten as subquery, I just think that cte is more readable